# How to Run the R script regardless of the location

Tags: r

I've got a R script that converts pdf tables to CSV. When I put all of the supporting files(CSV template, pdf, and the R code) in the code's specified location, it will run.

When I need to share this code with other users to run it regardless of the location specified in the code. How to do this?

**path**:

```
if (is.na(studyPath)) {
  scriptFilePath <<- "C:/Users/Desktop/RScript/"
  studyPath <<- "C:/Users/Desktop/RScript/"
  logFile <<-  "C:/Users/Desktop/RScript/"
  outDir <<- "C:/Users/Desktop/RScript/"
}
```

Comment: You need to make those paths into something you construct dynamically.  You could always put them in folders directly off of the working directory, for example.

Comment: @Elin, if you could give me any examples, it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: paste0(getwd(), "/mypath")  ... I did something like that here https://github.com/ropenscilabs/qcoder/blob/bfb54a770935740ff99118ea4e2825c7153599d2/R/read_in_files.R#L23  a little more complicated though.

Comment: Some advice can be found here: https://rstats.wtf/safe-paths.html. The recommendation is to use relative paths with the `here` package.

Comment: Not working this:rstats.wtf/safe-paths.html.

Comment: Are you saying the link doesn't work? (It works for me.) The information is also located here: https://github.com/jennybc/here_here#readme

Comment: It works now.. Thank you

Comment: `choose.dir()` might be useful if you want your users to find the folder in a point and click way, but of course sacrifices reproducibility